# How to count no of elements?

Tags: javascript, html

suppose i have

what i want is inside maindiv i want to count no of elements(may be div input tags)present.
there may be use of getElementByTagName().
But the problem is that how to count element.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue from [John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058937/how-to-count-no-of-elements/3058946#3058946), you may be looking for something like this, if I understand that you want to count the `div` and `input` children within the `id="maindiv"` element:

```
var maindiv = document.getElementById('maindiv');

var count = maindiv.getElementsByTagName('div').length +
            maindiv.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
```

Comment: @rajesh: What do you want dynamic exactly?

Comment: actually currently i am working on remote mapping in which my first activated cursor will be at home, now if i clicked on right arrow of remote then it must go to next tab (suppose services) Hence i am thinking that i must collect no of divs present in page ,then if i pressed right arrow he must know that my next div is this one and inside that i must focus on the first element(may be div input etc) 
.
Please give response asap.
Thanks

Comment: @rajesh: I think you may want to consider posting another question on this issue, maybe providing some examples.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want `getElementsByTagName()` rather than `getElementByTagName()`.

That function, given the appropriate parameter, will return a list of all the elements of that particular tag name (divs, p's, etc.)

On every list is a property `.length`, which will give you the count.

From [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName#Example):

```
// check the alignment on a number of cells in a table. 
var table = document.getElementById("forecast-table"); 
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) { 
    var status = cells[i].getAttribute("data-status"); 
    if ( status == "open" ) { 
        // grab the data 
    }
}
```

And I agree with @pranay_stacker; jQuery gives you a simpler way to get the info.